# GOOGLEFINANCE like function in BIGQUERY to turn value from 1 currency to another

Tags: google-bigquery

Right now I am working on something which needs to turn cost in (IDR) to (USD), so I wonder there is any function that I can use to do this in BIGQUERY?

Thank You!

Comment: As far as I know, you need to do this manually: https://blog.thereportapi.com/currency-rates-into-bigquery/

Comment: This feature is currently not available in BigQuery. If you want this feature in BigQuery, you can raise a feature request in [Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests).